# EDIT TEXT disabled on shapes in protected VBA worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have a heavily protected worksheet that uses VBA to dynamically create shapes.  The shapes are created, unlocked then the worksheet is reprotected. Here is a snippet for a textbox shape:

```
 Private Sub cmdTextBox_Click()
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim X, Y, Side As Single

    X = ActiveSheet.Range("D12").Left
    Y = ActiveSheet.Range("D12").Top

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, X, Y, 250, 30)
    Shp.Name = "textbox_" & ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count

    Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("textbox_" & ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)
    Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "Arial"
    Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = "16"
    Shp.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Shp.Fill.Transparency = 0.2
    Shp.Line.Transparency = 1
    Shp.TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
    Shp.TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
    Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
    Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Right-click to modify format"
    Shp.Locked = False

    ActiveSheet.Protect

  End Sub
```

This allows the user to (among other shape creation tools) create some shapes on a diagram sheet.  My issue is that the protected workbook (I want to limit the user to specifically what my dialogs allow them to place/enter for data) disables the "EDIT TEXT" option of any type of shape.  How do I either

A) Enable the "EDIT TEXT" option for unlocked shapes or... (preferred)

B) Detect that a shape has been selected (each shape is created with a name prefix like rect_ or circle_ for easy .name identification) in order to know when to unprotect the sheet to enable the "EDIT TEXT" option and then re-protect upon deselection or selection of something else? (slightly less desireable)

Answer (score 0):

Code taken from a qick recorded macro, protecting a sheet with 'Edit Objects' enabled:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

But, if you go to Format Shape>Properties instead there should be an option there for Lock Text. This would be my preferred option as the Edit Objects option allows them to be resized or deleted, this of course depends on what you actually want the users to be able to do with it.

Comment: The shapes are completely unlocked and the only objects directly editable on the sheet.  They are to be allowed to be resized, formatted and moved around.  The only thing they can't do that I need them to is to edit the textarea property directly.   I could do it with a dialog window, but I would prefer to allow users to right click the shape and use the Edit Text option.